# Internal working of inputFiles method in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I was reading about inputFiles() in  the documentation of pyspark . When I ran the below code it returned me output as 0.

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load("/data/spark/Spark-The-Definitive-Guide/data/retail-data/all/*.csv")
print(len(df.inputFiles()))
```

Please let me know why the output is zero and also a more verbose explanation of inputFiles() if possible. The explanation in the documentation is pretty dense .

```
Returns a best-effort snapshot of the files that compose this DataFrame. This method simply asks each constituent BaseRelation for its respective files and takes the union of all results. Depending on the source relations, this may not find all input files. Duplicates are removed.
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran the same command, got below output:

```
>>> df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load("file:////github/Spark-The-Definitive-Guide/data/retail-data/all/*.csv")
>>> print(len(df.inputFiles()))
1
>>> df.inputFiles()
['file:///github/Spark-The-Definitive-Guide/data/retail-data/all/online-retail-dataset.csv']
```

`inputFiles()` should show all input files. I suppose the reason you got 0 is the path is correct. You should use something prefixed with `file:///`